# How to split a string in shell and get without the last field

Tags: string, bash

I want to get a substring from a string without the last element, for instance 3 examples

```
toto=aa-bb-cc-element
toto=aa-bb-element
toto=ff-element
```

I want to `get aa-bb-cc` `aa-bb` `ff` in variable
the variable always have substring and `-` character, I want to delete the last substring `element`

I find to gest the last element

```
echo ${toto##*-}
```

Comment: Tip to remember shell variable expansions: `#` represents an eraser to erase from left to right of string \(like you'd do with your right hand). `%` represents scissors to cut-out the right-most tip of a string. Like you'd hold a string in your left hand while cutting it with scissors with your right hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find to gest the last element

And similarly to remove the last:

```
echo "${toto%-*}"
```